# Magento2 get the customer custom attribute option value

Tags: magento2, dropdown-attribute

In Magento2 observer, How can I get the customer custom attribute option value as my customer custom attribute in a dropdown.

I tried below code but it is not working in observer, it works in block

```
$option_val = $customer->getResource()
        ->getAttribute('att_code')
            ->getSource()
                ->getOptionText($customer->getData('att_code'));
```

I am getting this error Uncaught

> Error: Call to undefined method
> Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getResource()

This is how the options are added

```
public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Global')],
                ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('2')],
                ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('5')],
                ['value' => '4', 'label' => __('10')],
                ['value' => '5', 'label' => __('15')]
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
```

Comment: is it an extension attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerDataObject();
  $attrvalue = $customer->getData('attributeCode');
  or
  $attrvalue = $customer->getAttributeText('attributeCode');
```

Comment: Let me know if it works for you

Comment: sadly Not working...

Comment: what error are you facing ?

Comment: have updated answer

Comment: getting bank result

Comment: does your custom attribute has value ?

Comment: try
$customer->getCustomAttribute('attributeCode')->getValue();

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if($customer->getCustomAttribute('attributeCode') && $customer->getCustomAttribute('attributeCode') !== null) {
    $customer->getCustomAttribute('attributeCode')->getValue();
}
```